# Does uploading a file to HDFS automatically store the files in a distributed manner?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I just started learning Hadoop, and I am little confused regarding how the data is stored in a distributed manner. I have an MPI background. With MPI, we typically have a master processor that sends out data to various other processors. This is done explicitly by the programmer.

With Hadoop, you have a Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). So when you put some file from your local server into HDFS, does HDFS automatically store this file in a distributed manner without anything needed to be done by the programmer? The name, HDFS, seems to imply this, but I just wanted to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The file is uploaded, the NameNode coordinates the replication based on the replication factor (usually 3) to the DataNodes where it is stored.

In addition, the NameNode has a job that looks for under-replicated files or blocks and will duplicate them to maintain the replication factor.  See [HDFS Architecture - Data Replication](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current1/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication) for more information.